# How to change the static global variale declared in struts action class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts-1

I have global static boolean variable defined in struts-action class. How do i change its value from other Action class.

```
public class MyAction extends Action{

   public static boolean existsFlag = false;

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
                            ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws Exception
    {
         int a=10;
         if(a==10){
             existsFlag = true; // is this ok to use
         }
         return mapping.findForward("successDisplayForm");
    }

}
```

Also I have another Action class, where i want to set this value to 'false' when transaction gets completed.

Please help.

**Note : Using Struts-1.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other public static variable:

```
MyAction.existsFlag = true / false;
```

Comment: I am doing the same. But it has a random behavior.. Sometimes it sets the value to false. sometimes doesn't.

Comment: I think you are running into a race condition.  A web-app is always multi threaded so you probably have multiple threads updating this single variable at the same time.  If the transaction is per user (as it should be), I suggest using a session variable to indicate if it is done.

Comment: i am doing this in while loop with if else inside. Like i have for loop from i=1 to i=10. the condtion gets true at i=1 and after loop ends i.e. i=10, i want to make this variable to false.